# jqgrid not picking up style

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have jqgrid on my page and the data is loaded correctly but the style looks really ugly. I am loading these files:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.multiselect.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.widget.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui/minified/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've checked in Firebug and they all load correctly so there isn't any path problem for any of the scripts.

This is my actual jqgrid code:

```
  $('#brands').jqGrid({
            url: '/GasolineBrands/GasolineBrands/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Logo', 'Name', 'No of Stations'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Logo', index: 'Logo', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'No of Stations', index: 'No of Stations', width: 150, align: 'center' },
            ],
            shrinkToFit: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            loadonce: false,
            pager: jQuery('#brandsPager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Name',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'Gasoline Brands',
            width: '100%',
            height: "100%"
        });
```

This is my html:

```
<table id="brands">
                </table>
                <div id="brandsPager">
                </div>
```

Can anybody spot the problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please, post only the pure html code or better post all relevant code to http://jsfiddle.net. It is obviously a client issue only.

Comment: You'll need to define "ugly".  It'd be difficult to spot anything since you've only shown us "structural" things here - you've got a table and a div and 3-column grid, etc.

Comment: I found that I had to include     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. I did that and everything worked smoothly.

Comment: @Jaggu - you should post this comment as an answer and close the question out if you no longer need assistance with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to include `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")"` rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. I did that and everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

The order I use:

```
<link href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/jquery.multiselect.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/jquery.multiselect.filter.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/jquery.countdown.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"> 
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico">
<style>
    .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        white-space: normal !important;
        height:auto;
        vertical-align:text-top;
        padding-top:2px;
    }
</style>
```

Then the js files:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/grid.locale-en.js" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Then to my jqGrid I add the following:

```
altRows: true,
altclass: "ui-state-default",
```

Also resize the grid on load to fit the visible area.  Respond if you want that code too.

I should probably mention I theme my entire site with jquery-ui with the following:

```
<body class="ui-state-default">
```

Works for every theme I've tried and is pretty.  Hope it helps.